# SOAPFaultException detail is null

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, websphere-7, soapfault

I am calling a SOAP webservice using JAX WS. In the case of an error I am getting the following response from the client (I see this in my trace log):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP- ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>Error</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Error</faultstring>
        <SOAP-ENV:detail>
            <BLAServiceFault xmlns:ns="http://messages.testservice.com/TestService/2012/10">
                <ns:ReturnStatus>
                    <ns:ReturnCode>-97</ns:ReturnCode>
                    <ns:ReturnStatusSpecification>
                        <ns:SubCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <ns:Description>The price of productA must be higher than 30.</ns:Description>
                    </ns:ReturnStatusSpecification>
                </ns:ReturnStatus>
            </BLAServiceFault>
        </SOAP-ENV:detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

As you can see the useful error is in the detail node:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>  
<SOAP-ENV:Body>  
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>  
        <SOAP-ENV:detail>
```

In my client I am getting a SOAPFaultException which has a SOAPFault object. The SOAPFault object seems to be missing the node I posted above. SOAPFaultException.getFault().getDetail() is null.The exception is javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Error. How can i get the detail node with description?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the message that came from the service was not SOAP 1.1 compliant. After they have removed the prefix 'SOAP-ENV' from the 'detail' node it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the question. [Possible to consume badly formed Fault Messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610902/possible-to-consume-badly-formed-fault-messages/32589072#32589072)

```
} catch (SoapFaultClientException e) {
    log.error(e);
    SoapFaultDetail soapFaultDetail = e.getSoapFault().getFaultDetail();
    SoapFaultDetailElement detailElementChild = (SoapFaultDetailElement) soapFaultDetail.getDetailEntries().next();
    Source detailSource = detailElementChild.getSource();

    try {
        Object detail = (JAXBElement<SearchResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate().getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(detailSource);
//                throw new SoapFaultWithDetailException(detail);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot unmarshal SOAP fault detail object: " + soapFaultDetail.getSource());
    }

}
```